# How to Download a file placed in a image button - HTMLUNIT

Tags: javascript, java, download, jsoup, htmlunit

Download a file by clicking a image button.

I've this [link](https://bidset.nycsca.org/SitePages/Obtain%20Solicitation.aspx?SN=16-15323D-1&ReqType=Solicitation&IsDlg=1&IsDlg=1)

I've been trying to download the files (two save icon image buttons). When i click the image it prompts to download zip file.

This is the tag as seen in page's **VIEWSOURCE** of buttons

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$m$g_b265ad4d_cd49_41f3_a9f2_0090f0aa5504$ctl00$gvBidSetsFile$ctl02$ImageButton1" id="ctl00_m_g_b265ad4d_cd49_41f3_a9f2_0090f0aa5504_ctl00_gvBidSetsFile_ctl02_ImageButton1" title="Download" src="/SiteAssets/images/saveitem.gif" style="height:18px;width:18px;border-width:0px;">

    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
    HtmlPage homePage = null;
   // Document doc = null;  
    String base="https://bidset.nycsca.org/SitePages/Obtain%20Solicitation.aspx?SN=16-15323D-1&ReqType=Solicitation&IsDlg=1&IsDlg=1";

    try {
        client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    homePage = client.getPage(base);
    synchronized (homePage) {
        homePage.wait(5000);
    }
    System.out.println("file Page : " + homePage.getUrl());
   // Document dd = Jsoup.parse(homePage.asXml());
    HtmlInput docs= homePage.getFirstByXPath("//input[@id='ctl00_m_g_b265ad4d_cd49_41f3_a9f2_0090f0aa5504_ctl00_gvBidSetsFile_ctl02_ImageButton1']");

        homePage = bidDocs.click();
```

Questions:
As I get

```
HtmlInput docs =  homePage.getFirstByXPath
 ("//input[@id='ctl00_m_g_b265ad4d_cd49_41f3_a9f2_0090f0aa5504_ctl00_gvBidSetsFile_ctl02_ImageButton1']");
```

Is it ok to perform,

```
homePage = bidDocs.click();
```

here clicking on the save icon downloads file.

1. I m confused how could I download this file with help of HTMLUNIT . 
   I want to download file in my local drive .
2. Is it possible to get url link of homepage after  (homePage = bidDocs.click();)

i.e. store link , `String docurl=get homePage's link . ????`

3. If i could get the link I can use `BufferedStream` to download file .

   ```
       File file = new File("C:/TRY/file/abc.zip");
       BufferedInputStream in = null;
       FileOutputStream fout = null;
       try {
           in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(docUrl).openStream());
           fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

           final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
           int count;
           while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
               fout.write(data, 0, count);
           }
       } finally {
           if (in != null) {
               in.close();
           }
           if (fout != null) {
               fout.close();
           }
       }
   ```

I've to use `HTMLUNIT` here because it is `javascript`, `iframe` site.
Im thankful for you help.

Thank you verymuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting the file tag

```
 HtmlInput download = pageCheck.getByXPath("//input[@title='Download']");
```

and for streamming

```
 download.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream()
```